# Upgrading iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've XCode 3.2.3 with iOS SDK 4 installed in my iMac. I bought an iPhone 4 with OS version 4.0.2 and I would like to use that device for development. However the Organizer shows the message below when the device is connected.

The version of iPhone OS on “iPhone 4G” does not match any of the versions of iPhone OS supported for development with this installation of the iPhone SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iPhone SDK.

Currently my XCode supports Base SDK from 3.0 to 4.0.1.

So if I download the latest XCode 3.2.4 with iOS SDk 4.1, will I still have Base SDK support from 3.0 ?

Cheers
Jugs

Comment: It's worth noting that you can't submit apps to Apple that are built against the 2.x or 3.x SDKs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, XCode 3.2.4 does not come with SDK 3.0, it comes with SDK 3.2 and 4.1. But you don't need the 3.0 SDK to write apps that will run on 3.0.

There are two versions that are important to you as an iOS developer, and you need to understand them: first, there's SDK version that you **link to**, this is the **Base SDK**. It should normally be set to the newest SDK available.

And then, there's the **Deployment Target**. That is the **earliest version your app needs to run on**. This is the one you are actually caring about, this one ensures that your app will still run on earlier iOS devices.

To set that, go to "*Project -> Edit Active Target*". In the dialog, select the "*Build*" tab, make sure "*Show*" is set to "*All Settings*" and the type "deploy" in the search field. Scroll down to the "*Deployment*" section, the last entry should be "*iOS Deployment Target*". You need to set this to "*iOS 3.0*" or whatever suits you. <strike>You should now get warnings if you use methods or classes that are not available on 3.0.</strike>

Comment: Are you sure that you get warnings when using classes/selectors not available in 3.0? I've seen crashes but no warnings!

Comment: Oops, I double checked and you are absolutely right. No warnings.

Comment: Yep, you will definitely get no warnings if you use stuff which doesn't exist in the deployment target you've set.  The only way to be sure things work properly on your minimum deployment target OS version is to actually test with that version of the OS.